# How can I make NSURL cache?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsurl

My app does quite a few requests to a server. A lot of those requests refer to the same resources.

I would like to know if there's anything I should do to help both sides spare the time and effort and simply cache the responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, requests are cached for 60 seconds. This can be controlled with the `cachePolicy:` and `timeoutInterval:` parameters of `NSURLRequest`.

**Added:**

If you implement `connection:willCacheResponse:` in your `NSURLConnectionDelegate` then you can see which responses are cached.